# Alguém sabe me explicar o motivo do código ter dado um erro completo, desde já agradeço. Lembrando que a linguagem é C++, a do arduino

Tags: c++

#define bombA 44  // pino bomba de água 1 (presente no galão 1)
#define bombB 45  // pino bomba de água 2 (presente no galão 2)

#define pSA A2  //  pino para o valor analógico do sensor de  umidade da terra
#define pLvm 40 // pino Led Vermelho
#define pLa 41 // pino Led Amarelo
#define pLvd 42 // pino Led Verde
#define pino_sinal_analogico A3 // pino analógico do sensor de humidade da terra
int valor_analogico;

const int LNdA = 46; // pino Led Nível d'água
const int SNdA1 = A6; // pino analógico Sensor Nível d'água 1
const int SNdA2 = A7; // pino analógico Sensor Nível d'água 2

#include <LiquidCrystal.h> //Carrega a biblioteca LCD
#include <dht.h>     //Carrega a biblioteca DHT
#define DHTPIN A4       // Pino analog 4 para o DHT
dht DHT;
#define DHT11_PIN 7

LiquidCrystal lcd(30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35); // pinos ligados ao lcd
byte grau[8] = { B00001100,
B00010010,
B00010010,
B00001100,
B00000000,
B00000000,
B00000000,
B00000000,
};

#include <Wire.h>   //sensor de luminosidade
#include <BH1750.h>
BH1750 lightMeter; // Cria uma instância

void setup() {

Serial.begin(9600); //Inicia uma serial

lcd.begin(16, 2); // Inicia o LCD
lcd.clear(); // Limpa o LCD
lcd.createChar(0, grau); //Cria o caractere customizado com o simbolo do grau
dht begin();

Wire.begin();
lightMeter.begin(); //Inicia a medição de luminosidade

pinMode(pSA, INPUT);
pinMode(pLvm, OUTPUT);
pinMode(pLa, OUTPUT);
pinMode(pLvd, OUTPUT);

pinMode(bombA, OUTPUT);
pinMode(bombB, OUTPUT);

pinMode(LNdA, OUTPUT);
pinMode(SNdA1, INPUT);
pinMode(SNdA2, INPUT);
}

void loop() {

if (analogRead(SNdA1) < 550) {
digitalWrite(LNdA, HIGH); // Led de nível d'água baixo aceso 1
} else {
digitalWrite(LNdA, LOW); // Caso nível d'água alto/moderado, Led 1 não acende
}

if (analogRead(SNdA2) < 550) {
digitalWrite(LNdA, HIGH); // Led de nível d'água baixo aceso 2
} else {
digitalWrite(LNdA, LOW); // Caso nível d'água alto/moderado, Led 2 não acende
}

lcd.write((byte)0);
int chk = DHT.read11(DHT11_PIN);
Serial.print("Umidade = ");
Serial.println(DHT.humidity);

float lux = lightMeter.readLightLevel();
Serial.print("Luminosidade: ");
Serial.print(lux); // Imprime o valor de luminosidade no lcd
Serial.println(" lux");

valor_analogico = analogRead(pino_sinal_analogico);
if (valor_analogico > 0 && valor_analogico < 400) { // Status de solo úmido, led Verde aceso
digitalWrite(pLvd, HIGH);
digitalWrite(pLa, LOW);
digitalWrite(pLvm, LOW);
}

if (valor_analogico > 400 && valor_analogico < 800) { // status de solo moderado, led Amarelo aceso
digitalWrite(pLvd, LOW);
digitalWrite(pLa, HIGH);
digitalWrite(pLvd, LOW);
delay(150);
digitalWrite(bombA, HIGH);
delay(3500);
}

if (valor_analogico > 800 && valor_analogico < 1024) { // status de solo seco, led Vermelho aceso
digitalWrite(pLvd, LOW);
digitalWrite(pLa, LOW);
digitalWrite(pLvd, HIGH);
delay(150);
digitalWrite(bombA, HIGH);
digitalWrite(bombB, HIGH);
delay(5000);
}
}

Comment: Postagens duplicadas não são aceitas aqui, quem quiser tratar desse assuto pode fazer nesta postagem aqui, com o mesmo problema: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/535635/